# How does Tezos manage overflow in smart contracts (in 5-year old language please)?

Tags: smart-contracts

If Tezos was to shorn their full code set into a small 56bit processor it would cause overflow due to the sheer amount of transactions and overriding gas limit.

So it doesn't.

So...what process is used? But also what else does it do stop prevent overflow, as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For the `nat`, `int`, and `timestamp` types, the Michelson interpreter uses [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) provided by the OCaml [Zarith](https://github.com/ocaml/Zarith) library.

Comment: And what does that mean? Thanks!

Comment: It means that their size is only limited by gas or storage limits. You can store huge numbers in a contract without reaching the limit.